# Part of query from PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have built some webpages where I can analyze the revenue of a shop per day, week, month,  and year. Now, I want to use the same queries for these pages, except for the part where I compare the time:

For day this will be:

```
DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(order.timestamp)) = DATE(CURDATE())
```

And for week:

```
WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(order.timestamp), 3) = WEEK(CURDATE(), 3)
```

Now I want to put this string into a variable, which makes it possible for me to just include queries.php and make the query like this:

```
$time = "DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(order.timestamp)) = DATE(CURDATE())";

$rev_today_in = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(order.totale_prijs) FROM `order` WHERE order.medewerkerID != 2 AND '".$time."' AND order.totale_prijs >= 0"),0);
```

This is not working, and I haven't found any solution and whether or not this is possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You realise this (even when it is working) will give you problems when you have more than a year's worth of data in your database

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Because the server has to check the date for every timestamp? First I had order.timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) AND order.timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()). This works for today and the current month, but not for the week and year reports.

Comment: Not because the server has to check the date for every timestamp; but because 2014-01-01 and 2013-01-01 will both return a week number of 1, even though they're a year apart... you need to check against both week ___and___ year

Comment: Ok thanks, I will also add the year as a WHERE clause, which will fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might not work because you are quoting your time string. The extra `'` before
and after time need to go, otherwise it will be a string even to mysql.

-edit-

I wild guess is that when you remove the quotes you will get a mysql syntax error.
If this happens it might be because your field is named order and not quoted as a
field. Use backticks around fields if you have tricky names. Or avoid tricky names.

Comment: I just tried it, and it worked. I didn't know the ' needed to be there only when dealing with a string. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try this .

```
$time = "DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(order.timestamp)) = DATE(CURDATE())";
$query = "SELECT SUM(order.totale_prijs) FROM `order` WHERE order.medewerkerID != 2 AND '".$time."' AND order.totale_prijs >= 0";

$rev_today_in = mysql_result(mysql_query($query),0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I prefer the solution from monocell, because else I have to make a lot of new variables in my php files.